# Forward POST request from express to mail

Tags: node.js, express

I generate a pdf on client side with jspdf and send it to an express server with formData

```
var blob = pdf.output('blob');
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('pdf', blob);

$.ajax('http://localhost:8080/test/first',
 {
  method: 'POST',
  data: formData,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  success: function(data){console.log(data)},
  error: function(data){console.log(data)}
 });
```

The request arrives on the server, which I can see in my console, however, I don't see the body. I am new to node and express, so I am not really clear how to test this. However, the file doesn't need to be saved on server anyway, but just forwarded to a certain email. So I thought maybe, if I manage to forward, I can actually see my pdf as an attachement. Is there a simple way to forward this formData? I already have a sceleton for it, but I am stuck how to proceed.

```
exports.sendForm = async (body) => {
    try {
        console.log(body);
        // todo send form data to email: test@gmail.com

        return;
    } catch (err) {
        return next(err);
    }
};
```

Comment: how you're forwarding the mail?

Answer (score 0):

You can use multer to handle file upload, then you can access the file in route handler from req.file

Then you can send the file as a mail attachment using nodemailer

Multer - https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Nodemailer example with attachment - https://nodemailer.com/message/attachments